# Error al crear vista JSF usando "JSF from Entity Classes", [ Cannot be generated because EJB Lite classes are not available on project classpath. ]

Tags: jsf, ejb, netbeans-11

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto con JSF, pero cuando intento agregar una pagina jsf usando  "JSF from Entity Classes" me muestra el error de la imagen, ya intenté cambiar la librería de persistencia Eclipselink (JPA 2.1) a una de Postgresql, pero sigue igual, uso netbeans 11.1, busqué en la web pero no encontré la respuesta. Soy nuevo en java, gracias

Comment: Sería importante saber si estás es un proyecto Maven y tienes las dependencias necesarias.

Answer (score 0):

Investigando encontré que EJB Lite esta dentro de JEE versión 6;  le agregué la librería dando click con el botón derecho sobre la carpeta Libraries y seleccionando Add Library..., luego seleccione la versión Java EE 6 API library, y listo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]